# Как правильно делать pull request?

Tags: git, gitlab

Сделал форк, склонировал репозиторий на локальную машину. Отредактировал два файла, после чего создал ветку, в которой сделал:

```
git checkout -b new_branch
git add edited.file
git commit -m "Багфикс файла"
git push origin
```

Сделал pull request в веб-версии. Затем создал вторую ветку, в ней добавил второй отредактированный файл и сделал всё то же самое. Только почему-то при добавлении второго пулл-реквеста в нём оказался файл из предыдущего пулл-реквеста. То есть, тот файл, который я добавлял в совершенно другую ветку. Так и должно быть? Почему выкатываются не только те файлы, которые я добавлял в конкретной ветке?

Comment: «создал вторую ветку» на базе ветки new_branch, в которой уже есть файл, да?

Comment: @andreymal что значит "на базе" ветки? Если я создаю ветку и предварительно не вышел в `git checkout master`, то создаётся ветка на базе предыдущей?

Comment: Да, при создании ветки она ссылается на текущий коммит, которым, судя по всему, в вашем случае оказался коммит из new_branch

Answer (score 2):

Граждане, пожалуйста, читайте документацию. `git checkout -b new_branch` создает новую ветвь от текущего коммита, и это не обязательно master.

Теперь для исправления вам нужно сделать интерактивный rebase второй ветки на master. Ну или более вдумчиво прочитать `man git rebase` и найти способ перенести только коммиты из веки два, не входящие в ветку один. Такая команда есть, но за редкостью не помню.

Answer (score 1):

`git checkout -b new_branch` это ответвление от последнего коммита текущей выбранной ветки!

`git add edited.file` - добавление файла в ИНДЕКС текущей ветки.
Если сделать коммит файл и дальше будет отслеживаться Git'ом т.к. он находится в индексе.

Снова сделав `git checkout -b new_branch2` ответвление от коммита в ветке `new_branch` идексируемые файлы НЕ очищаются.

Нужно сделать `git rm -r --cached .` `rm` - удалить, `-r` - рекурсивно `--cached` - индексный кеш, `.` - текущий каталог.

`git add edited.file2` и тогда commit.

Но ошибка как раз таки в том что вы отвлетвляетесь от отвлетвленной ветки от master. - В вашем случае это и стало критической ошибкой.

Решение:

Ветка: master

`git checkout -b new_branch`

Вносим изменения -> `git commit` -> `git push origin`

Возвращаемся на ветку `master`

`git checkout master`

Снова отвлевляемся от ее последнего коммита

`git checkout -b new_branch2`

Вносим изменения -> `git commit` -> `git push origin`

И получаете два pull request'a

Обратите внимание дальше на то, когда вы хотите делать `merge` отвлетвленных веток  с изменениями/фиксами с веткой `master`